# I can't open selenium in vscode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

I just tried to test, but it is printing the same things.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\selenium\google.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
PS C:\python\selenium>
```

I installed selenium, but it isn't operating.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

No module named 'selenium' means you haven't installed selenium. So first run `pip install selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

### ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

this error means there's no `Selenium` **installed**.

See [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/installing_selenium_libraries/) to check how to install Selenium.

**Python**

Installation of Selenium libraries for Python can be done using pip:

```
pip install selenium
```

Alternatively you can download the PyPI source archive (selenium-x.x.x.tar.gz) and install it using setup.py:

```
python setup.py install
```